# Is it safe to use apple cider vinegar / baking soda to remove mold on (soft) plastic?

Tags: cleaning, mold, plastic

Will the (soft) plastic be eroded or produce bad chemical due to the low / high pH?

Comment: For mold, I'd use diluted bleach. A moldy piece of plastic either needs the mold removed or to be replaced. The worst case with bleach is the same as not effectively removing the mold.

Comment: Since it isn't particularly serious, I'm afraid that using bleach will be an overkill. Considering the chemical and/or gas it may produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon your mix, the PH may wind up at 7.0, exactly neutral. Vinegar (acetic acid) lowers the PH, baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) raises the PH.

Either is GENERALLY harmless to MOST soft plastics, whether alone or in combination. Do you have a specific plastic in mind? If it happens to be polyethylene ("polythene", to those on the opposite side of the Big Blue Wobbly Thing from me), that's nearly perfectly impervious to both vinegar and baking soda.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of plastic it is. It's around my bathroom's door to make it more "air tight". I'll try some vinegar on it then, to see whether I can remove the molds.

Comment: It may also be that the door seal may be harboring mildew as opposed to mold. There are specific products for helping to clean up mildew and mold. Look at the cleaning products section at your local hardware store.

Comment: After some Google Image Search it seems exactly like mildew. Thanks for pointing it out! :-)